# Score does not increment by 1 in Unity

Tags: unity

I have made a simple code where once the player moves through the collider that acts as a trigger then Unity adds a score. However, it increases by increments of 8 and I am not sure why.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Game : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int Score = 0;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {

        AddScore();
    }

    void AddScore()
    {

        Score++;

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you consider putting a breakpoint on your `Score++;` line to check when it was called?

Answer (score 1):

We cannot be sure of the exact issue without seeing how the scene is set up and what the player object consists of.  However, the problem seems to be that somehow when your player enters the collider it is triggering the event multiple times.

Some possible issues:

- The player is made up of 8 colliders
- Other objects are entering the trigger and interfering

Comment: Or the player skates along the edge of the trigger, entering and exiting rapidly. In particular, if the object is moved with its transform rather than with a rigidbody, this will produce a trigger exit/enter message pair every frame it stays inside the trigger, since raw transformation changes are handled like teleporting rather than sliding.